# The Bee's Knees -- still used in UK?

Tags: american-english, british-english, cliche

This nonsense phrase was exported along with American soldiers to England during ww2. Now, except for someone using it to be deliberately old-fashioned sounding, I would bet this phrase had not been used "unaffectedly" in 30 or maybe even 60 years anywhere in the USA. But I heard that some of these kind of phrases continued to be used in the UK long after the Yanks had gone home. Is this true? Is it possible that the bee's knees is used to this day and if not that particular phrase, any other phrase that probably originated in the USA but is no longer in common usage?

Comment: Google ngrams show recent (certainly since 2000) surges in usage of 'bee's knees' both in their US and UK corpora, but a brief look at examples does indeed seem to indicate almost all are in period or whimsical styles.

Comment: More common in UK now is the vulgar "it's the dog's bol*****."

Comment: *Please note that in BE, "Yanks" is somewhat derogatory/dismissive, and is rarely used.* Are you asking for a list of phrases that the US Forces brought to the UK and that are currently not in vogue? If you are, then the task is very time consuming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does the phrase "the bee's knees" originate from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47088/where-does-the-phrase-the-bees-knees-originate-from) From my answer there, *the US first came up with bees knees [in the '20s, **but**] it was actually the Brits who revived it ... in the 70s and 80s*

Comment: @OldBrixtonian it's a crudity I would never use!

Comment: 'The cat's whiskers' was the original, as far as I know. And I think the others were variants. People still said it in the '60's.

Comment: @Weather Vane I could tell by the coy asterisks!

Comment: @OldBrixtonian also "the cat's pyjamas" although I would like to coin "the fish's bicycle".

Comment: @Weather Vane I'll use it! I never heard the 'pyjamas' one. I remember the feminist slogan appearing on walls, 'A woman without a man is like a fish without a bicycle.' Naturally I disapproved of anyone who scribbled below it, 'A man without a woman is like a neck without a pain.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree that the expression is now some sort of whimsical throwback, used in light-hearted allusion to the days when it was current. I now never hear it used otherwise.

Comment: @FF Not really.